# Roboguice without android compat lib?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, roboguice, android-support-library

New Java and android developer here, so please be patient...

I've cloned roboguice from github and I was wondering if anyone can give me some pointers on how to recompile it so that it works with android 4.4. It's my understanding that Roboguice is using the compat lib and since my projects don't need to support previous android versions, it seems like I can't use it without relying on the compat lib. So, I've downloaded the source code and I was expecting to use some sort of preprocessor to ignore the classes that reuse the compat lib helpers. Unfortunately, it seems like java does not support any sort of preprocessing (am I wrong?), so I was wondering if there's anything else I can do (besides deleting the offending files from the project).

Btw, i'm using intellij for building the project.

Thanks.

Regards,
Luis

Comment: Have you considered using the combination of Dagger and ButterKnife instead of Roboguice?  Dagger isn't tied to Android so you wouldn't have any issues with compat lib and it's a lot faster to.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I'll take a look at those 2...